# Change a JavaScript export based on event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-admin

I'm using react-admin. I have `firebase.js`, which exports a data provider and an auth provider. Right now `firebase.js` looks something like

```
export const authProvider = MyCustomAuthProvider(...)
export const dataProvider = FirebaseDataProvider(..., {rootRef: "users/[authProvider.get~this~user().email]")
```

But I'd like the `dataProvider` imported to change when the user logs in / out (the reason being that the data provider has as its root collection at 'users/[user email]'). That's actually why I stopped using the `FirebaseAuthProvider` blackbox, because I figured I could use the login/logout functions to trigger changing the dataProvider.

What's the best way to accomplish this? Just declare the dataProvider using
`let dataProvider = null` and every time a user logs in/out, set that variable. And then add a function to the auth provider that returns that variable? There seems to be a more elegant way, but I'm not as experienced in JavaScript unfortunately.

Also for reference, the reason I'm taking this approach instead of just creating a dataProvider with rootRef 'users' and then accessing the correct collection / document when I want to view or modify data is because FirebaseDataProvider is a bit of black box and doesn't allow me to do that (unless I'm missing something). If I could get this all to work with FirebaseDataProvider, it *has* saved me a ton of time so that would be great.